# BI Tools Cognos, SSAS

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, cognos

I have a supertype dimension and subtype dimension data stored in same table.
I have a column in the table dimtype which is set to the id of subtype or supertype.
I would like to report data for supertype or subtype separately.
How can I do this through cognos or SSAS.

In cogonos I found a way where I can create filters. (Is this a good idea of using filters in cognos?)
But in ssas I dunno where I can create this type of filters.

Can any of you please suggest how to set filters on dimensions on ssas?

If I am using different tables for each supertype or subtype it works fine but customer has subtype, supertype data in same table which is causing problem while reporting.

Comment: Are you reporting from a cube or relationally? What is the actual error you get when you try something in report studio?

Comment: I am reporting from cube and i did not got any error while reporting.
I created two data source views for supertype and subtype and was reporting on both of them individually.
I would like to know if i can report on either supertype or subtype in a single data source view in SSAS

In cognos i created 2 filters for both of them, so whenever i want to report on either of them i would use appropriate filters.

Comment: So this is a general quesion about SSAS and Reporting Services. Is the reference to COgnos just explaining how you did it - there is no actual issue with Cognos?

Comment: Yes, this is general question about SSAS and Reporting Services.
To get an idea about problem i have used Cognos as an example.(not an issue in cognos)